# How to set utf-8 encoding in the uploading file when using apollo-upload-client?

Tags: node.js, stream, buffer, apollo, apollo-client

I am uploading a text file using `apollo-upload-client`. When the file hits the server it comes in `7bit` encoding, e.g.:

```
const { filename, createReadStream, encoding } = await file;
console.log({ encoding });

--> { encoding: "7bit" }
```

I then make a stream as follow:

```
const stream = createReadStream({ encoding: "utf8" });
```

and then a string out for the stream using the following function:

```
function streamToString(stream, cb) {
  const chunks = [];
  stream.on("data", (chunk) => {
    chunks.push(chunk.toString());
  });
  stream.on("end", () => {
    cb(chunks.join(""));
  });
}
```

the result:

```
streamToString(stream, async (data) => {
            
    console.log({data});

   --> good string �� good string ��

}
```

This is what gets saved in the DB `good string �� good string ��`.

I guess I need to send the file to the server with proper encoding, perhaps as `utf-8`. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `streamToString` function was implemented incorrectly. Here is the correct version:

```
 const chunks = [];

  readStream.on("data", function (chunk) {
    chunks.push(chunk);
  });

  // Send the buffer or you can put it into a var
  readStream.on("end", function () {
    res.send(Buffer.concat(chunks));
  });
```